# Power BI security

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am new BI and working on power bi reports embedded  into user application. How can I explain users about how data is secured in power bi. I am getting many questions about security. Can you kindly explain how you explained to your customers?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Once you embed(Publish) a report to website, all the people who can access that website link can access the report and data.
So its a way to share Power BI report for free.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using reports embeded in another application, if that application has integration with Azure then we can use Azure AD with that. Moreover, You can implement RLS, OLS and data masking in pbi, even in embeded mode.
Internally, datasets hosted in the PBI service are using Azure SQL in an encrypted mode. Even the credentials used to get data are encrypted.
If you want to explain customers, use the whitepaper of security.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-powerbi-security